# Proving $\sup A = -\inf(-A)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

In order to prove that

$$\sup A = -\inf(-A)$$

obs: $A$ is limited

I did:

think of $\sup A$ as a number

$$a\le \sup A, \forall a\in A \implies -a\ge -\sup A, \forall a\in A$$ Doesn't that implies that $-\sup A$ is indeed $\inf(-a)?$ I think I should prove that if there is another number that is in the middle, then this number cannot be the sup.

Also, why $A$ has to be bounded?

Comment: If the $sup$ exists, it has to be bounded above.  You don't know whether it's bounded below.  What do you mean by a "number that is in the middle?"

Comment: It shows that $(-\sup A)$ is a lower bound for $(-A)$. You have to show that it is the *greatest* lower bound.

Comment: What does obs mean?